# How to display a vector<uint16_t> image on MSVC

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio, buffer

I have a

```
std::vector<uint16_t> data_buffer
```

The data buffer is a depth image: uint16_t, 320x240.

I would like to watch it using the Image Watch plugin in MSVC.

I can't use OpenCV (not allowed in the project).

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: A little more info about context and what code you have already got would be helpful. Color image or Grayscale or other? What libraries do you have available if not OpenCV? What code are you putting this in?

Comment: If you cannot use OpenCV it should not be tagged as an OpenCV question. If you want to use Image Watch... the [documentation tells you](https://imagewatch.azurewebsites.net/ImageWatchHelp/ImageWatchHelp.htm#_Extensibility) how to view "User-defined image types"

Answer (score 0):

MSVC is an IDE. To do what you want you need to either write a library from scratch (aouchh!!!) or use an existing good one. Which one are you allowed to use?

Comment: He meant with "Image Watch", that is a plugin for VIsual Studio... The question is phrased in a confusing way... it is possible to display it without a proper library... but it requires several steps to make it work with image watch